# SublimeText: How to toggle curly braces to do-end blocks in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I'm using snippet quite frequently to write my code in SublimeText2. But there is one thing I can not achieve: toggling a block of curly braces to a block of do ... end.

Let's say i'm trying to build a multiline each-block. So I type:

```
[1,2,3].ea<TAB>
```

Which will result in:

```
[1,2,3].each { |e|  }
```

Now I need some magic to toggle it to:

```
[1,2,3].each do |e| 
  # cursor
end
```

I'm pretty sure there was a way to achieve this in TextMate, so there will be way in SublimeText, too. Any ideas?

**Update**:

I found the feature description in Textmate: ([TextMate shortcuts you should be using](http://szeryf.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/textmate-shortcuts-you-should-be-using/) -> Toggle ‘do … end’ / ‘{ … }’) ... that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more research, I found this plugin: https://github.com/irohiroki/RubyBlockConverter

It does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Create your new snippet for this:

Go to Tools -> New Snippet and insert something like:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[each do |${1:e}| $0 
    end]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>ead</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.ruby</scope>
    <description>each do |e| .. end</description>
</snippet>
```

Then save it and use it with ead[Tab]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I could do it, but this has to be done for each snippet that does something with blocks (map, inject, etc). Which would double the number of snippets. I'm looking for a more general approach.

Comment: You could generalize you snippet with more variables, for example one for list operation, another for block variable, etc. This would require more keystrokes though.